# google geocoding api services with zip code 12593

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I am having an issue with google geo-loaction services. essentially we are using it for a zip code validator and there is an issue with zip code '12593'. This zip code is showing as being in Spain. (see screenshot here = http://prntscr.com/hkkafh.

See xml here 
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?&address=12593)

This zip code though is a USA based zip code as can be seen here = https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=us+zip+code+12593&oq=us+zip+code+12593 (google search results.)

I understand that google is not the othority on zip codes however I would expect google to understand that this zip code may have two seperate locations.

any idea How I can get the api to understand I am looking for zip codes specifically in the USA?

Comment: That's not currently a valid zipcode:https://smartystreets.com/products/single-address?city=&state=&zipcode=12593&address-type=us-zipcode  |  You can also check that here:  https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupResultsAction!input.action?resultMode=2&companyName=&address1=&address2=&city=&state=Select&urbanCode=&postalCode=12593&zip=

Comment: Here are the zipcode around that (numerically)   
12583  NEVIS
12584  VAILS GATE
12585  VERBANK
12586  WALDEN
12588  WALKER VALLEY
12589  WALLKILL
12590  WAPPINGERS FALLS
12592  WASSAIC
12594  WINGDALE
12601  POUGHKEEPSIE
12602  POUGHKEEPSIE
12603  ARLINGTON
12604  POUGHKEEPSIE
12701  MONTICELLO
12719  BARRYVILLE

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think to check USPS as customer claimed was their zip code and found through Google search. If not at USPS either then I have nothing to worry. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zip code you're trying to find isn't reachable by the geocoding api. This near one is reachable:

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&components=country:US|postal_code:12516](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&components=country:US%7Cpostal_code:12516)

To search by zip code and restrict by country (i.e. US), you must use the subparameters of the `components` query parameter like in the URL above

`...&components=country:US|postal_code:[YOUR PARAMETER]`

(got this parameter info on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering)

Comment: The comment by Jeffery was more helpful to me but this answers my secondary question of how to force a country. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use https://thezipcodes.com/
Get the API key from account Section. Hit the get request. I found majority of data here.

```
https://thezipcodes.com/api/v1/search?zipCode={zipCode}&countryCode={2digitCountryCode}&apiKey={apiKey}
```

response will be like

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "location": [{
      "zipCode": "13040",
      "country": "United States",
      "countryCode2": "US",
      "countryCode3": "USA",
      "state": "New York",
      "stateCode2": "NY",
      "city": "Cincinnatus",
      "county": "Cortland",
      "latitude": "42.564381",
      "longitude": "-75.934792",
      "timeZone": "EST — Eastern Standard Time"
    }]
}
```